# How to retrieve a user profile picture in Liferay with javascript

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

I'm trying get user profile picture with javascript

```
  Liferay.Service('/user/get-user-by-screen-name',{
    companyId: Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getCompanyId(),
    screenName: 'marcio.sena'
  },
  function(user) {
    console.log(user)
    var url = '/image/user_portrait?img_id='+user.portraitId+'&&img_id_token=???????'
  }
);
```

how can I get **img_id_token** with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to your question, but something that might put you on the right track for figuring out:

(Disclaimer: I'm using the 7.2 source here, even though you tag Liferay 6, but you can repeat the actions on the source code matching your version. For readability I've shortened the paths and removed a few lines)

```
me@here:/..../liferay-dxp-7.2.10.1-sp1/src$ grep -r -5 img_id_token .
..../WebServerServlet.java-
..../WebServerServlet.java-           if (_userFileUploadsSettings.isImageCheckToken() && (imageId > 0)) {
..../WebServerServlet.java-                   String imageIdToken = ParamUtil.getString(
..../WebServerServlet.java:                           httpServletRequest, "img_id_token");
..../WebServerServlet.java-
..../WebServerServlet.java-                   if (user == null) {
..../WebServerServlet.java-                           user = UserLocalServiceUtil.fetchUserByPortraitId(imageId);
--
..../UserConstants.java-         if (_userFileUploadsSettings.isImageCheckToken()) {
..../UserConstants.java:                 sb.append("&img_id_token=");
..../UserConstants.java-                 sb.append(URLCodec.encodeURL(DigesterUtil.digest(userUuid)));
..../UserConstants.java-         }

me@here:/..../liferay-dxp-7.2.10.1-sp1/src$ grep -r -5 imageIdToken .
..../WebServerServlet.java-
..../WebServerServlet.java-           if (_userFileUploadsSettings.isImageCheckToken() && (imageId > 0)) {
..../WebServerServlet.java:                   String imageIdToken = ParamUtil.getString(
..../WebServerServlet.java-                           httpServletRequest, "img_id_token");
..../WebServerServlet.java-                   }
..../WebServerServlet.java-
..../WebServerServlet.java-                   if ((user != null) &&
..../WebServerServlet.java:                           !imageIdToken.equals(DigesterUtil.digest(user.getUserUuid()))) {
..../WebServerServlet.java-
..../WebServerServlet.java-                           return 0;
```

Takeaway:

- The token is configurable
- It's a digest of the UUID

The way it's generated makes me suspect that it *might* not be readily available on the JS side (without looking for it), but mimicking the digest, you can create it on your own.